# How to print the email after register in flash messages using cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
<?php
public function add(){

// code 

      $this->Flash->activateUsers('Thank you for choosing our website', $this->request->getData('email'));

}

?>
```

then I create a file inside src\Template\Element\Flash\activate_users.ctp with the content below:

```
<div class="message success">
       <?= h($message) , $this->request->getData('email'); ?>
                  or
       <?= h($message) ?> <?=h($this->request->getData('email')) ?>
</div>
```

But after successfull filling up the form with no error it will just print this:

> "Thank you for choosing our website"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$this->Flash->activateUsers('Thank you for choosing our website', [
    'params' => [
        'email' => $this->request->getData('email'),
    ]
]);
```

In your template:

```
<?= h($message) ?>, <?= h($params['email']) ?>
```

There's an example of this in the [Flash component section of the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/flash.html).

Comment: thank you, i read that and I thought it should have a key 'key' => 'positive',   and flash the message in the view <?= $this->Flash->render('positive') ?>
  is the positive a filename   positive.ctp?  can you further explain me about that docs

Comment: The 'key' is optional, it lets you write messages into different areas of the flash, which lets you do things like display them in different areas, show or hide them on specific pages, that sort of thing.